# How to replace a non routable IP address with server address on ftplib

Tags: python, ftps

I'm trying to use ftplib.FTP_TLS, but I can't list the directories.

Everything is OK with Filezilla, but when I'm on iPython, it fails.

```
import ftplib
from django.conf import settings  # just a config file


client = ftplib.FTP_TLS(timeout=10)
client.connect(settings.HOST, 21)
client.auth()
client.prot_p()
client.login(settings.USER,settings.PWD)
client.set_debuglevel(2)
client.retrlines('LIST')
```

Here is the return of this last command :

```
*cmd* 'TYPE A'
*put* 'TYPE A\r\n'
*get* '200 Type set to A.\r\n'
*resp* '200 Type set to A.'
*cmd* 'PASV'
*put* 'PASV\r\n'
*get* '227 Entering Passive Mode (10,191,x,x,238,54).\r\n'
*resp* '227 Entering Passive Mode (10,191,x,x,238,54).'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
timeout                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.pyc in <module>()
----> 1 client.retrlines('LIST')

/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.pyc in retrlines(self, cmd, callback)
704             if callback is None: callback = print_line
705             resp = self.sendcmd('TYPE A')
--> 706             conn = self.transfercmd(cmd)
707             fp = conn.makefile('rb')
708             try:

/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.pyc in transfercmd(self, cmd, rest)
366     def transfercmd(self, cmd, rest=None):
367         """Like ntransfercmd() but returns only the socket."""
--> 368         return self.ntransfercmd(cmd, rest)[0]
369 
370     def login(self, user = '', passwd = '', acct = ''):

/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.pyc in ntransfercmd(self, cmd, rest)
679 
680         def ntransfercmd(self, cmd, rest=None):
--> 681             conn, size = FTP.ntransfercmd(self, cmd, rest)
682             if self._prot_p:
683                 conn = ssl.wrap_socket(conn, self.keyfile, self.certfile,

/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.pyc in ntransfercmd(self, cmd, rest)
325         if self.passiveserver:
326             host, port = self.makepasv()
--> 327             conn = socket.create_connection((host, port), self.timeout)
328             try:
329                 if rest is not None:

/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.pyc in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address)
569 
570     if err is not None:
--> 571         raise err
572     else:
573         raise error("getaddrinfo returns an empty list")

timeout: timed out
```

Like I said, it works fine with Filezilla. But I can see something special :

```
Commande :  PASV
Réponse :   227 Entering Passive Mode (10,191,x,x,236,94).
Statut :    Le serveur a envoyé une réponse passive avec une adresse non routable. Adresse remplacée par celle du serveur.
```

The «Statut» lines means something like: «Server send a passive response with a non routable address. Address replaced by the server one».

It seem this is the way to make it work.

My question is: How can I do the same with ftplib? Or is there another option for me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you know where to connect to. I think the key may be in this line 326:

```
325         if self.passiveserver:
326             host, port = self.makepasv()
--> 327             conn = socket.create_connection((host, port), self.timeout)
328             try:
329                 if rest is not None:
```

You can subclass and replace the `makepasv()` method and return the right address.
Maybe you can use the output of filezilla or wireshark to get to know the right address.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Not beautiful because I manually send the correct host, but it works.
Could it be a feature if libftp do the same as Filezilla, check if the ip is routable, use the host if not ?

Comment: I know this is old, but I am desperate. Can you put up some code, and where you put it in ftplib? I attempted this, and rewrote makepasv(), but now I am getting protocol errors.

Comment: Can you post your code in a new Question referencing this? I do not know where you got stuck. I can write down some untested code but I am not sure it works for you.