# Connecting to FTPS with Python

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, python-3.6, ftps

I am trying to connect to an FTPS server which requires anonymous login with a .pfx certificate.

I have been given instructions for how to access it through the gui application SmartFTP which does work, thus I know I haven't got any firewall issues etc. However, for this workflow getting access to it through python would be ideal.  Below are the settings I have been given:

```
Protocol: FTPS (Explicit)
Host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Port: 21
login type: Anonymous
Client Certificate: Enabled (providing a .pfx file)
Send FEAT: Send before and after login
```

I am having trouble picking the python module best suited to this with a full example using a .pfx certificate. Currently I have only tried the standard FTP module using the below code. Does anyone have a worked example?

```
from ftplib import FTP_TLS

    ftps = FTP_TLS(host='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
                   keyfile=r"/path/to.pfx"
                   )
    ftps.login()
    ftps.prot_p()
    ftps.retrlines('LIST')
    ftps.quit()
```

Using the above code I get:

```
ValueError: certfile must be specified
```

Client versions:
  Ubuntu == 14.04,
  Python == 3.6.2

### Update

Think I am a little closer with the code below but getting a new error:

```
from ftplib import FTP_TLS
import tempfile
import OpenSSL.crypto


def pfx_to_pem(pfx_path, pfx_password):
    """ Decrypts the .pfx file to be used with requests. """
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.pem') as t_pem:
        f_pem = open(t_pem.name, 'wb')
        pfx = open(pfx_path, 'rb').read()
        p12 = OpenSSL.crypto.load_pkcs12(pfx, pfx_password)
        f_pem.write(OpenSSL.crypto.dump_privatekey(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, p12.get_privatekey()))
        f_pem.write(OpenSSL.crypto.dump_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, p12.get_certificate()))
        ca = p12.get_ca_certificates()
        if ca is not None:
            for cert in ca:
                f_pem.write(OpenSSL.crypto.dump_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert))
        f_pem.close()
        yield t_pem.name


pfx = pfx_to_pem(r"/path/to.pfx", 'password')
ftps = FTP_TLS(host='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
               context=pfx
               )
ftps.login()
ftps.prot_p()
# ftps.prot_c()
print(ftps.retrlines('LIST'))
ftps.quit()
```

**Error:**
ftplib.error_perm: 534 Local policy on server does not allow TLS secure connections.

Any Ideas?

Cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting to 'Explicit FTP over TLS' in Python (??)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44057732/connecting-to-explicit-ftp-over-tls-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you try to do SFTP. FTP over SSL is not the same as SFTP. As far as I know SFTP (which is related to SSH) is not possible with the standard library.

See this for more about SFTP in Python: [SFTP in Python? (platform independent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432385/sftp-in-python-platform-independent)

Comment: Nope, unfortunately it is FTPS which is using a client side SSL certificate not ssh. A wired set up that was not my choice.