# Override method of class in another file

Tags: python, class, overriding

Say I have two files, **file1.py** and **file2.py**. In **file1.py**, I define two classes, one inherits from the other:

**file1.py:**

```
class Class1:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def func1(self):
        return "Hello world!"

class Class2(Class1):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def func2(self):
        return self.func1()
```

So now I'm able to call `func1()` and `func2()` from `Class2`.

**file2.py:**

```
import file1

class Class3(file1.Class2):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

**Question:** How can I change `func1()` from `Class1` in **file2.py**, so that `func2()` in `Class2` returns the same as `func1()`?

So not like this:

```
class Class3(file1.Class2):
    ...
    def func1(self):
        return "Another string"
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want, but it sounds like `Class3` should not inherit from `Class2` if simply overriding `Class3.func2()` is not the solution.

Comment: @chepner It's a bit tricky, the above is only a skeleton of a class in the Python standard library (defined in file1.py). file2.py is my own file, I want not to change the code in the file in site-packages!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would overriding `func1` work?

```
class Class(file1.Class2):
    def func1(self):
        print "Class3.func1"

c = Class3()
c.func2()
```

Since `func2` is not defined in `Class3`, `Class2.func2` is called. However, in the body of that function, `self` is still an instance of `Class3`, so `self.func1()` calls `Class3.func1`, not `Class1.func1`. That is different from

```
d = Class2()
d.func2()
```

where `self` in `Class2.func2` is an instance of `Class2`. `Class2` does not define `func1`, so `Class1.func1` is called.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot, that works! I have not thought about that, but while `func1()` is not defined in `Class3`, it seems to be a fine solution. I've used this to override a function from `FTP` class in `ftplib` module in my class which inherits from `FTP_TLS` which inherits from `FTP`... :)

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to monkeypatch `Class1.func1`.

```
c2 = Class2()
print(c2.func2())
Hello world!

def new_func1(self):
    return "Another string"

Class1.func1 = new_func1  # This is monkey patching.

print(c2.func2())
Another string
```

But this might break other code that uses `Class1` or `Class2`.

Comment: This modifies the behavior of all classes with `Class1` as an ancestor, not just `Class3`.

Comment: @chepner I know, hence the "this might break stuff" bit. It looks to me that's exactly what the OP is asking for: "How can I change func1() from Class1 in file2.py..." but as you said it's not entirely clear what they want.

Comment: @linusg I tried to provide an answer to this question, I don't even understand your previous question about ftplib and "I cant make this working" is not a very useful hint.

Comment: @Goyo While english is not my native language, I may have problems in describing a problem sometimes (this is the first time sb. mantioned that). Any improovements of how I can make my question more clear are welcome. BTW, I cannot understand the downvotes.

Comment: @linusg You already accepted an answer to this question so I don't think you need to improve it. If you mean the other question, commenting here is not going to help.