# When trying to download files using a Python FTP_TLS object getting AttributeError?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, ftp

```
from ftplib import FTP_TLS
import socket
import ssl

class tyFTP(FTP_TLS):
    def __init__(self, host='', user='', passwd='', acct='', keyfile=None, certfile=None, timeout=60):
        FTP_TLS.__init__(self, host, user, passwd, acct, keyfile, certfile, timeout)
    def connect(self, host='', port=0, timeout=-999):
        if host != '':
            self.host = host
        if port > 0:
            self.port = port
        if timeout != -999:
            self.timeout = timeout

        try: 
            self.sock = socket.create_connection((self.host, self.port), self.timeout)
            self.af = self.sock.family
            self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(self.sock, self.keyfile, self.certfile, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
            self.file = self.sock.makefile('rb')
            self.welcome = self.getresp()
        except Exception as e:
            print e
        return self.welcome

# FTP_ROOT_PATH = "/outgoing/"
FTP_SITE = "..."
# FTP_SITE = "..."
FTP_PORT = 990

UPLOAD = {
    "USERNAME": "...",
    "PASSWORD": "..."
}

DOWNLOAD = {
    "USERNAME": "...",
    "PASSWORD": "..."
}

remote_file = "..."
local_filepath = "..."

server = tyFTP()
server.connect(host=FTP_SITE, port=990)
server.login(user=DOWNLOAD['USERNAME'], passwd=DOWNLOAD['PASSWORD'])
server.prot_p()
server.retrbinary("RETR " + remote_file, open(local_filepath, "wb").write)
```

I've copied some code already from this post [Python FTP implicit TLS connection issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164470/python-ftp-implicit-tls-connection-issue). I have a good understanding of everything that is going on in the code but am completely lost with the error. The issue is I am able to run everything up until the last line when I'm calling the retrbinary function. I am getting the error:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'wrap_socket'
```

The full error dialogue is:

```
File "sample.py", line 48, in <module>
server.retrbinary("RETR " + remote_file, open(local_filepath, "wb").write)
File "C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda2\lib\ftplib.py", line 718, in retrbinary
conn = self.transfercmd(cmd, rest)
File "C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda2\lib\ftplib.py", line 376, in transfercmd
return self.ntransfercmd(cmd, rest)[0]
File "C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda2\lib\ftplib.py", line 712, in ntransfercmd
conn = self.context.wrap_socket(conn,
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'wrap_socket'
```

Does anyone have any insight on what the culprit might be?

Comment: Could you __please__  let us know the whole code....Seems like `FTP_TLS`  is created somewhere else...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your use of the timeout arg (which is an int) is in the PLACE of the context variable in this line:

```
FTP_TLS.__init__(self, host, user, passwd, acct, keyfile, certfile, timeout)
```

Should be:

```
FTP_TLS.__init__(self, host, user, passwd, acct, keyfile, certfile, context, timeout)
```

See: 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you very much.