# FTP doesn't connect ends up with "EOFError"

Tags: python-3.x, ftp, ftps

I am trying to connect to connect to a FTP site to download some files:

```
from ftplib import FTP_TLS
from ftplib import FTP
import ssl
import ftplib


FTP_TLS.ssl_version = ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2
ftps = FTP_TLS(timeout=100)    
ftps.set_debuglevel(2)     
ftps.connect('IP', port)
ftps.auth()
ftps.prot_p()
ftps.login('username', 'password')
```

The program tries for sometime before it fails with the following error:

> *get* '' 
>       Traceback (most recent call last):   File "FTP.py", line 12, in 
>       ftps.connect('IP', port)   File "C:_data\learn\Miniconda\lib\ftplib.py", line 155, in connect
>       self.welcome = self.getresp()   File "C:_data\learn\Miniconda\lib\ftplib.py", line 236, in getresp
>       resp = self.getmultiline()   File "C:_data\learn\Miniconda\lib\ftplib.py", line 222, in getmultiline
>       line = self.getline()   File "C:_data\learn\Miniconda\lib\ftplib.py", line 210, in getline
>       raise EOFError EOFError

I am not sure what the cause of this error is . I can connect to the ftp server using the same details with a FTP client (FileZilla). Can anyone point out if there is issue with my code and possible options to fix this.

**Edit 1**

As suggested below posting FileZilla logs :

> ```
> Status:   Connecting to IP:Port...
> Status:   Connection established, initializing TLS...
> Status:   Verifying certificate...
> Status:   TLS connection established, waiting for welcome message...
> Status:   Logged in
> Status:   Retrieving directory listing...
> Status:   Directory listing of "/" successful
> ```

FIleZilla explicitly pops up a certificate which I press OK on my desktop after which the connection is established. I am assuming the failure here is because my code doesn't accept the certificate. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you running FileZilla on the same machine as your Python code? Show us its log file.

Comment: Updated as suggested.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl thank you for your suggestion. I started looking at a different perspective once I looked at FileZilla file in details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone looking for an answer, the issue was that implicit FTPS connections need the socket to be ssl wrapped automatically.I used the below piece of code written by [George Leslie-Waksman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4853563/george-leslie-waksman)

```
import ftplib
import ssl

class ImplicitFTP_TLS(ftplib.FTP_TLS):
    """FTP_TLS subclass that automatically wraps sockets in SSL to support implicit FTPS."""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._sock = None

    @property
    def sock(self):
        """Return the socket."""
        return self._sock

    @sock.setter
    def sock(self, value):
        """When modifying the socket, ensure that it is ssl wrapped."""
        if value is not None and not isinstance(value, ssl.SSLSocket):
            value = self.context.wrap_socket(value)
        self._sock = value
```

If this resolves your issue, kindly upvote the original answer -->https://stackoverflow.com/a/36049814/392233